# How to scrape html code which is inside JavaScript in selenium with htmlunitdriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, htmlunit-driver

I wanna access input field, for entering username in selenium with headless browser

And this is the code

`document.write("<input name='username' type='text' id='username'/>");`

How to access and enter the value when the HTML code is written inside JavaScript?

Comment: Why dont oyu enable javascript on the browser and edit the value when the elements are added to the DOM ?

Comment: I want it to work in headless mode(no popup) so I am using HtmlUnitDriver

Answer (score 0):

When you write to the document, you add to the DOM, so you should be able to get the element by ID from the DOM.

Comment: In selenium using chrome I can but while using headless browser like HtmlUnitDriver I couldn't access JavaScript